# Get link picker custom field to show only if field exists

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to get a url to a custom field to display only if it is not empty. could someone please explain what i am doing wrong so that i may learn from this, i am new to php and Im really struggling to figure this out.

example 1 displays the link whether field is empty or not however when it is empty, it links to the blog post instead of the link picker field, when it is not empty the link points to the correct field.

```
<div class="my_link">

<?php if($mylink = get_field('article_link') ): ?>

<div class="your_custom_class">

<a href="<?php echo ($mylink[url]); ?>"target="">Link to Article</a></div> 

<?php endif; ?> </div>
```

example 2 only shows if the field is not empty and does not show when the field is empty but it is not a url link to the custom field and just echos the correct url to the link.

```
<?php if($mylink = get_field('article_link') ): ?>

<?php echo($mylink[url]); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thankyou very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing if assigning a value to `$mylink` was successful in the `if` statement rather than testing if it's empty.

Try something like:

```
<?php 
    $article_link = get_field('article_link');
    if( $article_link['url'] ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $article_link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $article_link['title']; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See Example 1 [in the ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/hiding-empty-fields/).

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I have attempted this method, yet the link still shows and i can not understand why , and what is even more beyond me is, if the field is empty the url links to the current blog post, and if i add a link to the link picker field it links to that link, what relation does this custom field have to current post url?

Comment: Try explicitly checking if the field is not empty with something like `if (!empty(get_field('article_link')))`. Linking to the current page is default browser behaviour for empty links.

Comment: I tried earlier with if isset and empty and even when there was no link attatched it was saying it is not empty

Comment: I am new to web design and was hoping if you could suggest any ideas to the cause of this, honestly at wits end at the moment, been at it all day and still no luck.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump` on `get_field('article_link')` (put it on your page template) and see what is returned for both "empty" and "non-empty" links.

Comment: for empty links return is: array(4) { ["url"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["target"]=> string(0) "" ["postid"]=> string(0) ""    For non empty links: array(4) { ["url"]=> string(75) "http://mydomain/documents/salary-package-benefits-facilities-of-pilots/" ["title"]=> string(47) "SALARY PACKAGE, BENEFITS & FACILITIES OF PILOTS" ["target"]=> string(0) "" ["postid"]=> string(4) "6109" }

Comment: now i realise i am not trying to hide the output of the echo but the div which contains the output of the echo, how would i hide/display the div based on the condition whether the field is empty or not. The reason for this is since regardless if the field returns a value or not the text after the url "Link to Article" is always visible, What i am trying to do so is hide the entire div which contains the url.

Comment: Updated my answer. `get_field` is returning an array which tests true whether it has values set or not since it has keys set.

Comment: Thankyou a million mistertaylor, you have literally saved my life, your updated answer works as I had intended, there is one issue though, the link outputs the entire array again instead of just the url, i have replaced the_field('article_link') with echo ($article_link[url]), which does the job, once again I am really grateful for your help, i do not know what i would have done if you had not helped.

Comment: my apologies, I am new to stack exchange, I did not know that was an option, once again im very much obliged for all the help, Thankyou! :)